# XSD to HTML form

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd, jaxb

**What I want to do:**

I'm basically trying to create a tool which generates a HTML form where the data can be entered, which gets stored in the corresponding XML file. The HTML form in itself needs to be created with the help of the given XSD.

**Problems I faced:**

1. I converted the XSD file into JavaObjects by executing a DOS Command
   (xjc.exe filename.xsd ). The created Java files don't have the
   restrictions.
2. If the restrictions aren't available then the form will take in random values.
3. Can't figure out a way to convert the XML file into an HTML form .

If there is any other way out for this problem , I'm all ears. I'm new to XML and XSD so having a hard time figuring it out. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: XML is usually transformed to HTML using an XSLT.

Comment: In my final degree project I did something similar but using javascript+html5+css3 for the app instead of Java. There were some java/scala based solutions such as [dynaform](https://github.com/reinra/dynaform) ([see video](https://github.com/reinra/dynaform/blob/master/thesis/thesis-demo.avi)) and [xsd-forms](https://github.com/davidmoten/xsd-forms) ([see web-service](https://xsd-forms.herokuapp.com/)).

Comment: See also JAXFront and MetaWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm basically trying to create a tool which generates a HTML form
>   where the data can be entered, which gets stored in the corresponding
>   XML file. The HTML form in itself needs to be created with the help of
>   the given XSD.

You are describing [**XForms**](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/#waXForms), which never achieved widespread support, but which **should be understood before endeavoring to build solutions in this area**.  There have been many implementations, but see in particular [**XSLTForms**](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.htm), which is based on XSLT, JavaScript, and HTML and is open source.  Use or at least study it.

> I converted the XSD file into JavaObjects

There's **no real need to introduce Java**.  You need HTML and JavaScript, minimally, and XSLT is the ultimate in transforming XML.  Java offers little advantage to your endeavor, other than possibly hosting the XSLT transformation if you wish that they be performed server-side.

Comment: I converted the xsd file into a customized xml file and then converted it to an html form where the user can input the data and the call the web service. @kjhughes

Comment: That's fine, of course, but my suggestion is that the steps where an XSD is converted and where an XML file is converted would be best done using XSLT, not Java, and that you can learn a lot from XForms in general and XSLTForms in particular if you're looking for ideas.  Good luck.